# Force Update Event in Kendogrid Inline editing

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

i have a Kendo grid as shown in the image. which uses inline editing. For each record there are associated Disciplines as shown right below the grid. User selects edit record and then he selects the relevant discipline checkboxes and update the record. This scenarion works fine until user does some change to the text inside the textboxes of the grid (Document Type/Description). If the user do not change any text and just change the checkbox selection, then the record is not updated because the update event is not fired if user does not do any changes to the text.

How can i force the update event in this scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you've asked but in my case this helped:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<GenericDto>()
...
      .Events(e => e.Save("saveChanges"))

function saveChanges(e) {
    e.model.dirty = true;
}
```

if you want to call update on 'unchanged' row you have to set it dirty

I'm not sure how you want to make grid post your "checkbox data" unless those are being held in some hidden columns and rewritten from checkboxes below on checkbox change event